# ¿Por qué no se renderiza el contenido de mi plantilla?

Tags: python, django

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto, pero me está arrojando este mensaje de error y no doy con el inconveniente:

```
Error during template rendering

In template /home/didier/Documents/Projects/inventory/inv/templates/index.html, error at line 11  
Reverse for 'elements.views.element_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': 1}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Views.py:

```
def element_detail(request, pk):
    element = get_object_or_404(Element, pk=pk)
    template = loader.get_template('element_detail.html')
    context = {
        'element': element
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^element$', views.hello, name='hello'),
    url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.element_detail, name='detail'),
]
```

Index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block page_title %}
    Element list | RegiX
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    {% for el in element %}
        <li>
            {{ el.manufacturer }} ::
            <a href="{% url 'elements.views.element_detail' pk=el.pk %}">
            {{ el.model }}
            </a>
            {{ el.date_purchase }} ::
            <img src="{{ el.image.url }}">
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

La idea de la [resolución inversa de URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) es que justamente uses en el template el nombre que has definido para el patrón de tu URL mediante el parámetro `name` del a función [url()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.url).

Por lo tanto, para hacer uso de la resolución inversa en los templates es necesario que uses el nombre que has definido. En este caso sería:

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' pk=el.pk %}">
```

Ten en cuenta que si has definido un `namespace` para tu aplicación es necesario que lo incluyas en el nombre. Si has usado algo como esto:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^inv/', include('inv.urls', namespace='inv')),
]
```

Tendrías que usar entonces:

```
<a href="{% url 'inv:detail' pk=el.pk %}">
```

Si no estás usando `namespace` te recomiendo que lo hagas así evitas que existan conflictos entre las URLs de las aplicaciones.

### Referencias

- [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/urls/)
- [URL namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces)

Answer (score 1):

La línea 11 que indica el error dentro de tu index.html es:

```
 <a href="{% url 'elements.views.element_detail' pk=el.pk %}">
```

Defines en tu `Urls.py` en `urlpatterns` un patron :

```
 url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.element_detail, name='detail'),
```

por lo tanto debes cambiar a:

```
<a href="{% url 'elements.detail' pk=el.pk %}">
```